# routerlink second parameter get "undefined" instead of its value

Tags: angular, routerlink

i want the functionality of writing  in the input bar, and when i press the button, i want it to pass me to: "../search/".
but instead i get "../search/undefined".

this is the code:

`<input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="searchedValue">`

and:

```
<button [routerLink]="['/search', searchedValue]" routerLinkActive="is-active">search</button>
```

what do i do wrong?

Comment: First provide complete code. You are referring to `searchedValue` variable. `undefined` means that this variable is not in scope. Where do you define this variable?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to check

[(ngModel)]='searchedValue'

Answer (score 0):

`ng-model` binding is from AngularJS. In Angular2+ you need to bind to `ngModel`. You could also use two-way binding to have back and forth communication between the controller and template. Try the following

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="searchedValue">
```

Comment: like i wrote to chedly here, with [(ngModel)] the page doesn't even load. 
so i guess i'm doing something even worse?